# How to integrate Admeris Payment Systems in joomla?

Tags: php, joomla, payment-gateway, payment

How to integrate Admeris Payment Systems in joomla?

Comment: You are going to have to be more specific than that. Are you using a shopping cart extension? Which one? If not, how are you planning on determining what a visitor is buying?

Comment: hi Brent ..!! thks 4 ur response...!! i need to develop site like
http://www.bravotelecom.com/bravo/ in joomla.. in this bravo site have 3 telecoms plans..Each plan have some sub plans..!! 
The User can select there needed plan and pay with Admeris Payment Systems....!!! if u hav any idea?? pls help me frd...!!

Comment: Brant i have Account Expiration Control component and Open Source Excellence component for Paid Membership & Subscriptions..!!

Comment: neither of those two things is an e-commerce system. From a few moments in Google, Admeris supports only one Joomla-based e-commerce system.  You'll want to use that specific system, otherwise you'll need to do all of the integration yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the OSE extension, but I have used AEC. If you have never developed a payment plugin before, I would recommend getting in contact with Valanx, the developers of AEC. They have dozens they support and could probably implement an Admeris integration much easier than you could on your own.

Otherwise, as Charles mentioned, you will want to switch to Virtuemart. If you are doing one time payments for products, then VM will work well. If you need to do recurring payments, then you will want to use AEC.